# Anylogic event triggering via variable update

Tags: anylogic

In the agent I'm trying to build, I have a Dynamic Variable that could be changed from outside and I would like to link this change to trigger an event or a statechart transition.

I tried the condition `variable != 0` but it has 2 errors: It doesn't consider the `0` in the case it happens to appear and it locks my agent because that's an always `true` condition.

Do you know if this is something that could be done with Anylogic? Or should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical correct solution would be:

1. make your variable `private` (so it cannot actually be changed at all from external sources)
2. create a `public` function named `setMyVariable` that accepts a double argument named `newValue`
3. in that function, write `myVariable = newValue;`. Below that line, you can now execute any additional code that should be triggered whenever your variable is updated

This is the OOP way of doing things :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a lengthy solution, but I use it when nothing else works. Create dummy source and sink blocks inside the agent that flowchart lives. Be sure to select "calls of inject() function" inside the source.

[image]

And in the main, whenever that condition occurs, inject a dummy agent into that source block.

[image]

There you can control the transitions whenever the agent is created in the dummy source block with the variables that you have inside that agent.

Comment: This is an interesting workaround, but try my solution in the future. It is also in line with good OOP principles and Java coding :)

Answer (score 0):

To add just one more type of solution for completeness: for these kind of situation I prefer to use message passing. The first part is similar to OOP method - make the `variable` private so it can't be directly changed from outside the agent. Then to change the variable send agent a message using AnyLogic's [agent communication](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/communication.html) functions. Once the message that value has changed is received, it changes the value and then forwards it to the statechart to trigger a transition. This addresses your issues:

1. '0' can be acted on when necessary and
2. statechart isn't locked up as you only react to value change not to it's value